# Extract a word from a line

Tags: text-processing

Created a file employees:

```
1. Fred
2. Billy 1
3. Sally 1
4. Jim 2
5. Jane 2
6. Sue 3
7. Meg 3
```

Created a file “managers”:

```
1. Fred
2. Bill
3. Sally
```

I want to print something like this:

```
Fred

Billy Fred

Sally Fred

Jim Billy

Jane Billy

Sue Sally

Meg Sally
```

Comment: @heemayl This is the question.

Comment: One answer is two write two loops, one nested in the other with a conditional in the middle seeing if they are equal. You should attempt the details yourself. Feels like homework/test/exam/interview.

Comment: Not exactly. I will have a test and i am preparing for it by doing some exercises from past exams. This was an exercise that i could not do it without help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk way:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $2,a[$3"."]}' managers employees 
Fred 
Billy Fred
Sally Fred
Jim Bill
Jane Bill
Sue Sally
Meg Sally
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently file “managers” is included in "imployees". So

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2; print $2, a[$3"."]}' employees
```

should be enough.